# Replacing multiple if statements with a single if statement

Tags: java, if-statement

My code is supposed to take a string and if this string == "Help" it will do task X and if this string = "10.0.0.i", it will do task Y. Here is the code:

```
if(message.equals("Help")) {
                            //do X
}
else if ((message.equals("10.0.0.1")){
                                //do Y
    }
else if ((message.equals("10.0.0.2")){
                                //do Y
    }
else if ((message.equals("10.0.0.3")){
                                //do Y
    }
else if ((message.equals("10.0.0.4")){
                                //do Y
    }
.
.
.
```

I'm new to java. Since in message = "10.0.0.i" only the last character is changing and this code is going to implement task Y for all of them, I want to know if it's possible to replace all these conditionals statements `if ((message.equals("10.0.0.i"))` with a single "if" (instead of writing separate `if`s for "10.0.0.1", "10.0.0.2" etc.).

Comment: please try the switch command

Comment: @Guido You mean using different cases? but what if `i` ranges from 1 to 100? should I write 100 cases which all are supposed to do the same task?

Comment: you're right. didn't catch that all of them "do Y".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If only the last character is changing for messages starting with "10.0.0", you could use [`startsWith()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith(java.lang.String)) for the other cases than "Help":

```
if (message.equals("Help")) {
   //do X
} else if (message.startsWith("10.0.0")){
   //do Y
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use a regular expression:

```
if ((message.matches("10\\.0\\.0\\.[1234]")) {
    // do Y
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another option with type casting.

```
    int i=9;

    if(message.equals("Help")) {
                        //do X
    }else if ((message.equals("10.0.0."+String.valueOf(i))){
                        //do Y
    }
```

Comment: That is not typecasting, that is conversion.

Comment: I think it is type casting. type conversion is automatically done by compiler on the other hand type casting done by programmer explicitly.

Comment: @MuhammedIqbal But the programmer did not explicitly cast any type here. Type casting involves a type wrapped in parentheses, for example `String s = (String) someExpression()`.

Answer (score 0):

Guys you are getting overly complicated with this solution.  If it says help do x, if it says something else do y

```
if(message.equals("Help")) {
                        //do X
}
else {
    //do y
}
```

he didn't say that y had to do 100 different things only that everything other than help had to do y. so a very simple if/else statement is all that is needed.

Comment: now lets say that someone put in something other than help or a 0.0.0.i string.  That should be caught before doing the conditional input check and negated.

Comment: or do the input check inside the else statement.